# Cannot get mixed C and Ada program to link with pthread library

Tags: c, linux, gcc, ada, gnat

I am writing a program in C. I am getting the error:

```
file_name.c:(.text+0x5d): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
```

This specific error comes up when gcc is linking my file_name.o with my main ADA file.

For the actual compilation of the C file, I have tried using both:

```
gcc -c -pthread file_name.c
```

as well as:

```
gcc -c file_name.c -lpthread
```

Neither of these seem to work. Any thoughts?

**UPDATE:**
One thing I did not realize is that when combining C and ADA, the C libraries are included when using [`gnatmake`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Switches-for-gnatmake.html).

The problem was solved by using:

```
 gnatmake ada_file.adb -o -largs c_file.o -lpthread
```

Comment: Show us how you link your code.

Comment: `gcc -c` does compiling but no linking.  What command are you using to link, where the actual error occurs?

Comment: The linking is being done by `gnatmake`. The actual linking part is done using the gnatmake flag `-largs` that is followed by `file_name.o`

Comment: Update the question to show the actual linking line.  You'll need to add something to it to make the linker scan the pthread library.  And it appears that the problem is in the `gnatmake` facility — it isn't linking what you need to link.  Suggesting that GCC is at fault seems like it might be misdirecting the blame.

Comment: The actual line is inside of a make file. But, it is roughly `gnatmake main.adb -o -largs c_file_name.o`

Comment: That is not updating the question: it is adding another comment.  Please edit the question to include the relevant information.  Is `gnatmake` the Gnat linker process?  If so, you might need to add `-lpthread` after the `c_file_name.o` argument.  Or you might need to RTFM on `gnatmake`.  Does Gnat allow you to mix Ada threads with POSIX threads?

Comment: Yep I just figured that out, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `-c` switch, you are not linking your code. You are simply compiling it into object files. There's no point in specifying the libraries at this stage. Your `-l` parameter is simply ignored - it has no effect and no meaningful purpose when `-c` is present.

The libraries are supposed to be supplied at the moment of *linking*,  i.e. at the moment when you combine your object files into the final executable (without `-c`, of course). You are not showing us that command line. That linking line is exactly where you have to add your `-lpthread` parameter.

Comment: I did not include my linking code. What I included was just for compiling the stand alone C file. gnatmake is what does the linking.

Comment: @user289882: Great. But, as I said above, that line is irrelevant. There are no problems there. That line does not produce the error you quoted. The error is produced by your *linking* line. That's where you are supposed to specify `-lpthread`. And you haven't.

Comment: Okay I added it to gnatmake and it worked, thanks. I am new to using ADA so it is more or less a learning experience right now. Thank you!

Comment: @user289882: One thing to keep in mind: It's "Ada", not "ADA". It's not an acronym, it's named after a person.

Comment: I say ADA instead of Ada because of a convention in the company / project that I work on. It is purely out of habit. I know that it is not an acronym.